# Drawing specific rectangle of a Bitmap into another Bitmap

Tags: c#, graphics, gdi+

I have a big Bitmap in size - the entire MAP of my game. However, I want to draw a specific rectangle from it - not the entire map, so it can fit on game's screen.
Here is my method:

```
private void drawMap(Graphics g, ref Point location)
{

}
```

In the same class, I have a field of `Size`, called `viewSize` which gives the size of the game's screen. I have another field of `Bitmap`, called `Map`, too.

So, method `drawMap` should draw the specific `location` in `Map` with size `viewSize` into `g`.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I have made the `location` passed by reference so the performance is better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void drawMap(Graphics g, ref Point location)
{
    // Draw the specified section of the source bitmap to the new one
    g.DrawImage(Map, location.X, location.Y, viewSize.Width, viewSize.Height);
}
```

Comment: We have drawn on g1. I want the drawing on g parameter

Comment: @Mr.DDD: you edited my post in this way!! If you want to draw on `g`, simply comment first two lines and use `g` in place of `g1`.

Comment: @Mr.DDD: I restored my post. Is this what you need? :D